# How can raise events for the buttons created dynamically in ag-grid cell-rendered?

Tags: typescript, angular, ag-grid

Hie I am using ag-grid angular2 where i am trying to place a button in every row which i am successful.when i click on that button i adding an event listener to the button so that when this button is clicked i want to raise an event.
This is how i am adding buttons to every row

```
    {headerName: "Gold", field: "gold", width: 100,  cellRenderer: this.ageCellRendererFunc },
```

Here i am writing the addeventlistener logic for the button

```
ageCellRendererFunc(params) {
    var eSpan = document.createElement('button');
    console.log(params);
    eSpan.innerHTML = 'Del';
    eSpan.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.raiseevent();
    });
    return eSpan;
}
```

This is the event which i want to raise when the button is clicked

```
raiseevent(){
alert('code worked');
}
```

But it is showing an error saying raiseevent is not defined...How can i correct this mistake...How can i give the reference of an event inside addeventListener...Somebody please help me

Comment: Unlike ag-grid, PrimeNG grid is a native angular2 component, with templating you can bind events of any content in cells. Here is the demo with a button. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatabletemplating

Answer (score 10):

This site: http://www.flyingtophat.co.uk/blog/2016/02/19/workaround-for-angular2-event-binding-in-ag-grid-cell-templates.html has an answer that I think will work for you.  It is ugly because you have to listen to the generic onRowClicked event and then inspect the event to identify what button got pressed, but it should work.

Example:

```
<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid class="ag-fresh"
    rowHeight="10"

    [columnDefs]="columnsDefs"
    [rowData]="rowData"

    (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)">
</ag-grid-ng2>

@Component({
    directives: [AgGridNg2],
    selector: "user-table",
    templateUrl: "../user-table.subhtml"
})
export class TableComponent {
    public columnDefs = [
        { headerName: "Username", field: "username" },
        { headerName: "Actions",
          suppressMenu: true,
          suppressSorting: true,
          template:
            `<button type="button" data-action-type="view" class="btn btn-default">
               View
             </button>

            <button type="button" data-action-type="remove" class="btn btn-default">
               Remove
            </button>`
        }
    ];

    public onRowClicked(e) {
        if (e.event.target !== undefined) {
            let data = e.data;
            let actionType = e.event.target.getAttribute("data-action-type");

            switch(actionType) {
                case "view":
                    return this.onActionViewClick(data);
                case "remove":
                    return this.onActionRemoveClick(data);
            }
        }
    }

    public onActionViewClick(data: any){
        console.log("View action clicked", data);
    }

    public onActionRemoveClick(data: any){
        console.log("Remove action clicked", data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please add the relevant information directly (for example a few lines of code that demonstrate the essential part of how to do it)

Answer (score 2):

Use `=>` instead of `function`

```
eSpan.addEventListener('click', () => {
```

otherwise `this` doesn't point to your class when the callback is called.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: If i change my code to 
eSpan.addEventListener('click', () => {
this.raiseevent()
})   then also it is showing the same error like this  -> cannot read property raiseevent of undefined

Comment: Hard to tell from the few code fragments in your question.

Comment: I will produce a plunker demo asap